# MongoDB simple aggregation with lookup performance improvement

Tags: mongodb, nosql, pymongo

So I have the following query in mongoDB:

```
[
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      id: 1,
      uniqueId: 1,
      shortLabel: 1,
      "geographicLocation.id": 1,
      "economicConcept.id": 1,
      "frequency.id": 1,
      "scale.id": 1,
      "unit.id": 1,
      source: { $arrayElemAt: ["$source", 0] },
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "geographic_location",
      localField: "geographicLocation.id",
      foreignField: "id",
      as: "region",
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          $or: [
            { "region.name": "United States" },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      metadata: [
        { $count: "total" },
        { $addFields: { page: 1 } },
      ],
      data: [{ $skip: 0 }, { $limit: 10 }],
    },
  },
]
```

However it is pretty slow for the amount of records in D (200k). I am trying to improve this query but I am not sure why approach is not working.

I already added indexes on `id` on `geographic_location` collection which the lookup is running on. But it seems its not using this index and instead is going for `COLSCAN` stratety. `Match` stage is also too slow, but again I placed indexes.

This is how explain results for the query look like:

```
{
  "stages": [
    {
      "$cursor": {
        "queryPlanner": {
          "plannerVersion": 1,
          "namespace": "ihs_markit_data.unique_ids_in_each_bank",
          "indexFilterSet": false,
          "parsedQuery": {},
          "queryHash": "57975262",
          "planCacheKey": "57975262",
          "winningPlan": {
            "stage": "PROJECTION_DEFAULT",
            "transformBy": {
              "uniqueId": true,
              "shortLabel": true,
              "id": true,
              "geographicLocation": {
                "id": true
              },
              "_id": false
            },
            "inputStage": {
              "stage": "COLLSCAN",
              "direction": "forward"
            }
          },
          "rejectedPlans": []
        },
        "executionStats": {
          "executionSuccess": true,
          "nReturned": 230045,
          "executionTimeMillis": 12134,
          "totalKeysExamined": 0,
          "totalDocsExamined": 230045,
          "executionStages": {
            "stage": "PROJECTION_DEFAULT",
            "nReturned": 230045,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 331,
            "works": 230047,
            "advanced": 230045,
            "needTime": 1,
            "needYield": 0,
            "saveState": 254,
            "restoreState": 254,
            "isEOF": 1,
            "transformBy": {
              "uniqueId": true,
              "shortLabel": true,
              "id": true,
              "geographicLocation": {
                "id": true
              },
              "_id": false
            },
            "inputStage": {
              "stage": "COLLSCAN",
              "nReturned": 230045,
              "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 70,
              "works": 230047,
              "advanced": 230045,
              "needTime": 1,
              "needYield": 0,
              "saveState": 254,
              "restoreState": 254,
              "isEOF": 1,
              "direction": "forward",
              "docsExamined": 230045
            }
          },
          "allPlansExecution": []
        }
      },
      "nReturned": 230045,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 360
    },
    {
      "$lookup": {
        "from": "geographic_location",
        "as": "region",
        "localField": "geographicLocation.id",
        "foreignField": "id"
      },
      "nReturned": 230045,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 11840
    },
    {
      "$match": {
        "region.name": {
          "$eq": "United States"
        }
      },
      "nReturned": 114639,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 12004
    },
    {
      "$facet": {
        "metadata": [
          {
            "$teeConsumer": {},
            "nReturned": 114639,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 12123
          },
          {
            "$group": {
              "_id": {
                "$const": null
              },
              "total": {
                "$sum": {
                  "$const": 1
                }
              }
            },
            "nReturned": 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 12134
          },
          {
            "$project": {
              "total": true,
              "_id": false
            },
            "nReturned": 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 12134
          },
          {
            "$addFields": {
              "page": {
                "$const": 1
              }
            },
            "nReturned": 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 12134
          }
        ],
        "data": [
          {
            "$teeConsumer": {},
            "nReturned": 10,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0
          },
          {
            "$limit": 10,
            "nReturned": 10,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      "nReturned": 1,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 12134
    }
  ],
  "serverInfo": {
    "host": "",
    "port": ,
    "version": "4.4.0",
    "gitVersion": ""
  },
  "ok": 1
}
```

Any idea what is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to improve the performance of this operation, but what is your target? Do you want to reduce the time by 10%, meet a specific SLA, or something else perhaps? How frequently will this operation run? Will the data continue to grow?

Overall there is not enough information here for us to sufficiently answer the question. That said, there are still a number of observations and pointers that we can make. I suspect there may be a schema issue here though, and it seems pretty unlikely that you will be able to achieve your desired performance with the current approach.

At a high level, here is what the database is doing to execute this aggregation:

- Doing a full collection scan of the `230,045` documents in the source `unique_ids_in_each_bank` collection. This is because you are not limiting the data coming from that original collection in any way. This is why you see the references to the `COLLSCAN` in the `explain` output. Each of these documents is transformed via the `$project` stage before being passed to the subsequent stages for further processing.
- For each of those input documents (so `230,045` times), performing a `$lookup` into the `geographic_location` collection. The `$lookup` operation *could* use a compound index on `{ id: 1, name: 1 }` for the example query above, but it is unclear if that would change the performance in any meaningful way. There are improved metrics in the `explain` output for `$lookup` in newer versions of the database.
- About half (`114,639`) of the original documents still belong in the result set after the `$match` stage and are passed on for further processing.
- One of the two subpipelines for the `$facet` is counting all of the incoming documents. Therefore all `114,639` documents will streamed into this stage and processed before it can return the results (count and first 10 items) to the client.

  - Note also that the other subpipeline is doing a skip + limit to perform pagination, which itself [can be slow and inefficient](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/#using-skip--) as the data set grows.

It looks like it takes the database about 12 seconds to scan the full collection, do 230k lookups into another collection, and then process all of those results. That is a lot of work to be done, and there really isn't an index or something that meaningfully changes that.

Some potential things to consider:

- Creating the compound index noted above, though that will likely only result in a marginal improvement at best.
- Issue separate queries for the count and for retrieving the results. While the count will still be slow, the query that retrieves the (first page of) results would no longer have a blocking stage and should return much quicker. This would slow down as the `skip` value grows.
- Change your schema. Is it going to be common to combine this `geographic_location` information into documents from the source collection? If so then forcing the database to generate new documents every time the data is read may be a heavy burden.

Finally, keep in mind that pagination without a (unique) sort may lead to [unexpected results](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/#using-skip---with-sort--).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Regarding your last point about changing schema, do you mean that I should avoid lookup in this case? I can kind of see this is a bit like relational database design so probably not the best case for mongo? 
As for limiting initial scan- are there any methods for this?

Comment: Also if I understand correctly it takes 11s for the `$lookup` to run compared to 1s for initial scan and some miliseconds for match and remaining operations, from this explain results?